# Nothing returned if the column with the WHERE condition has an index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, mariadb

Working on Debian 11 (Bullseye) first with the distribution's MariaDB version 10.5 and now with the version 10.6.7 from MariaDB repositories.

I'm failing to get correct indexes for some big tables from the dump of a genetics database (ensembl homo_sapiens_variation_106_37) from here: ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/grch37/release-106/mysql/homo_sapiens_variation_106_37/

The one table is variation_feature:

```
CREATE TABLE `variation_feature` (
  `variation_feature_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `seq_region_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `seq_region_start` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seq_region_end` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seq_region_strand` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `variation_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `allele_string` varchar(50000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ancestral_allele` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `variation_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `map_weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flags` set('genotyped') DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `consequence_types` set('intergenic_variant','splice_acceptor_variant','splice_donor_variant','stop_lost','coding_sequence_variant','missense_variant','stop_gained','synonymous_variant','frameshift_variant','non_coding_transcript_variant','non_coding_transcript_exon_variant','mature_miRNA_variant','NMD_transcript_variant','5_prime_UTR_variant','3_prime_UTR_variant','incomplete_terminal_codon_variant','intron_variant','splice_region_variant','downstream_gene_variant','upstream_gene_variant','start_lost','stop_retained_variant','inframe_insertion','inframe_deletion','transcript_ablation','transcript_fusion','transcript_amplification','transcript_translocation','TFBS_ablation','TFBS_fusion','TFBS_amplification','TFBS_translocation','regulatory_region_ablation','regulatory_region_fusion','regulatory_region_amplification','regulatory_region_translocation','feature_elongation','feature_truncation','regulatory_region_variant','TF_binding_site_variant','protein_altering_variant','start_retained_variant') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'intergenic_variant',
  `variation_set_id` set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `class_attrib_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `somatic` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `minor_allele` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `minor_allele_freq` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `minor_allele_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `alignment_quality` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `evidence_attribs` set('367','368','369','370','371','372','418','421','573','585') DEFAULT NULL,
  `clinical_significance` set('uncertain significance','not provided','benign','likely benign','likely pathogenic','pathogenic','drug response','histocompatibility','other','confers sensitivity','risk factor','association','protective','affects') DEFAULT NULL,
  `display` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`variation_feature_id`),
  KEY `pos_idx` (`seq_region_id`,`seq_region_start`,`seq_region_end`),
  KEY `variation_idx` (`variation_id`),
  KEY `variation_set_idx` (`variation_set_id`),
  KEY `consequence_type_idx` (`consequence_types`),
  KEY `source_idx` (`source_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=743963234 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It has over 700,000,000 records and occupies on the disk:

```
# ls -lh variation_feature.*
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 56K Mai  3 09:41 variation_feature.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 55G Mai  2 20:44 variation_feature.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 61G Mai  2 22:27 variation_feature.MYI
```

Despite not getting any errors importing the variation_feature.txt some essential indexes are not working.
In this case, selecting a known row of data based on variation_id won't return anything, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM variation_feature 
WHERE variation_id = 617544728;

--> nothing
```

The value 617544728 seems not to be in the index, because

```
SELECT variation_id 
FROM variation_feature 
WHERE variation_id = 617544728;

--> nothing
```

Disabling the index and waiting for the long table scan returns the row:

```
ALTER TABLE variation_feature ALTER INDEX variation_idx IGNORED;

SELECT * 
FROM variation_feature 
WHERE variation_id = 617544728;

variation_feature_id  seq_region_id  seq_region_start  seq_region_end  seq_region_strand  variation_id  allele_string  ancestral_allele  variation_name  map_weight  flags   source_id  consequence_types  variation_set_id                                                                             class_attrib_id  somatic  minor_allele  minor_allele_freq  minor_allele_count  alignment_quality  evidence_attribs                 clinical_significance  display
--------------------  -------------  ----------------  --------------  -----------------  ------------  -------------  ----------------  --------------  ----------  ------  ---------  -----------------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ---------------  -------  ------------  -----------------  ------------------  -----------------  -------------------------------  ---------------------  -------
           632092737          27511         230845794       230845794                  1     617544728  A/G            G                 rs699                    1  <null>          1  missense_variant   2,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,23,24,25,26,30,40,42,43,44,45,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57                2    false  A                        0.2949                1477             <null>  368,370,371,372,418,421,573,585  benign,risk factor           1
```

myisamchk is fixing the indexes without error, but the index "variation_idx" won't work.

DROPping and re-CREATing the one index runs without error, but the index won't work.

The other indexes are OK.

In another genome of this database (ensembl homo_sapiens_variation_106_38 - slightly bigger) from here: ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-106/mysql/homo_sapiens_variation_106_38/ I have the same problem (on another computer but with the same program installations).
With one difference: there is also the PRIMARY KEY (variation_feature_id) not working.

myisamchk is also running without error, but to no avail.

mysqlcheck (version 10.6 running very slow compared to 10.5) returns on the first computer then:

```
homo_sapiens_variation_106_37.variation_feature
error    : Key in wrong position at page 22405134336
error    : Corrupt
```

Now, this we know, but no repair tool can really repair or give a hint, what's wrong.

I've CREATEd an index on variation_name: it's working.

My changes to mariadb.cnf to adapt to the huge databases and the mysql versions of ensembl:

```
[mysqld]

## this was some time ago - because some bug mysql or mariadb didn't took this from the system
default-time-zone = Europe/Berlin

## ensembl has mysql version 5.6
## because of table creation scripts I need compatibility:
show_compatibility_56 = ON
performance_schema

## ensembl writes in DATETIME fields: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
## the new sql_mode in 5.7 doesn't allow it any more
## SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode' ;
## ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
## so change sql_mode deleting NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE
sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

datadir = /mnt/SRVDATA/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir  = /mnt/WORK/tmp

[mariadb]

[mariadb-10.6]

## MyISAM for building ensembl homo_sapiens
lower_case_table_names=1

bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1G
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 56G
sort_buffer_size = 56G
```

Thank you for the patience to read all this.

---

Edit, unresolved, supplementary information, March 3, 2023

10 months later I'm bumping this with supplementary information.

I'm working now on a Workstation with 2 Xeons and 96 GB ECC RAM. The hard drives are new.

MariaDB is on Debian 11 (bullseye) in the version: "Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.9.5-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline EditLine wrapper"

The database I need is already three versions further and the files can be found under ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-109/mysql/homo_sapiens_variation_109_38/

I encounter the same issue trying to load the variation_feature.txt (which is 103G big and contains 747758162 lines/records).

I tried both MyISAM and ARIA engines with the same described effect.

Despite "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE", myisamchk and aria_chk running and ending with success, I can select a record based on a condition on the PRIMARY KEY or variation_idx only if I disable the indexes (and wait a long time).

If I run a mysqlchk the table will be marked as faulty with a key in wrong index position.

The same cycle all over again: loading OK, mysqlchk NOT OK, repairing OK, mysqlchk NOT OK!

Following the recommendation to use InnoDB I started the "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" with "set unique_checks=0" 7 days ago (is still running), having the following customized innodb configs:

```
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 76G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
```

top shows MariaDB has reserved 83.4Gb virtual resources and filled actually 79Gb IN RAM but uses only ~2% CPU.
iotop shows a poor disk activity of ~0.5-2Mb/sec.

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: Your question is very detailed, which is good, but I'm missing some crucial information, you probably might have omitted because you didn't think of it. 1. You only give one example of a non-working `variation_id` value. Do the others all work, or not? 2. It is unclear what you've actually tried to repair the table. The only vague statement you give is: _"no repair tool can really repair or give a hint, what's wrong"_. What did you try?

Comment: Yes, I tried also other values for variation_id. None returns something. Trying on the other database having also the PRIMARY KEY problem, yes, I tried a couple of values; noting returned something. I tried repairing with mysqlrepair and myisamchk; as said without errors, but without really fixing things

Comment: Details do matter. Did you stop the database before the repair? Did you try the `-e` or `-f` option? There are other options as well. Try them.

Comment: Yes, 1) I stopped the database before myisamchk. 2) I locked the table before DROP INDEX and CREATE INDEX.  3) but mysqlrepair was not --extended. I didn't think that --force would make sense, because I didn't got any SQL errors with the three methods so far. I have just started a mysqlrepair run with --extended. It will take a while. It's a trial of patience to have to run repairs extended after the long job of importing the big tables. It's the same pattern on two different computers with sufficient CPUs running on 64GB respectively 96GB RAM. Many thanks for your suggestions. Till then

Comment: I downloaded the file, and yes, it is big. 728,624,284 rows. Using another database engine might indeed be a good idea, but instead of using InnoDB you might want to consider [MariaDB Aria](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aria/). MariaDB says: _"You're encouraged to use the Aria storage engine, rather than MyISAM, for new applications, which has even better performance and the goal of being crash-safe."_

Comment: I'm in your debt, keeping you busy with this issue that late. Thank you! Ensembl is a huge scientific resource for bioinformatics and keeps to this model since decades, having much success and delivering to a whole world of scientists. They offer it all open source and I try to follow their steps with pretty much the same tools. I failed. Didn't think the data would be corrupt, I thought, my using of MariaDB could be rather a question for the DB-informatics. Given the complexity of their databases, I would unhapiiy edit their source database creating SQLs to another shape. Recov still on route

Comment: Status report to mysqlrepair --extended: it's running now since 14 hours. This is not really a suitable method for contemporary databases. I'll wait another couple of hours and kill it, DROP the table and reCREATE it. On a second thought it would be less painful to edit all CREATE TABLES of the Ensembl *.sql files to ENGINE=MARIA if it should work better

Comment: Yes, extended repairs can take very long. I'm a bit baffled by this problem. Nothing indicates that this could occur, even with MyISAM. I would try ARIA (not MARIA), and see if that helps. Just to be sure, can you [check the health of your hard drives](https://www.simplified.guide/linux/disk-health-check)? Not that I think it's that, but you never know. Better be sure.

Comment: Good point with the drives! On a computer I hat a couple of UDMA_CRC_Error_Counts seemingly ~2 years ago. On the other one no errors. This problem happens on both of them. I let the extended run running; curious how long it will take and what it brings. On the other computer I began already loading the same dump.txt in a second table CREATEd with "ENGINE=ARIA TRANSACTIONAL=0"

Comment: Here only a progress report about using the ARIA engine. On one computer I could build good indexes for the huge table. On the second computer I got the same result, as with MYISAM, meaning a bad index I couldn't fix either with aria_chk (which run without error). Unfortunately these tests are time and ressource consuming and I must work also other things for a living. What a pity - not to discover a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, it is a pity you didn't find a reason for the errors.

Comment: Alas still unresolved. I added a followup and supplementary info to my original message

Answer (score 0):

`sort_buffer_size` should be limited to 1% of RAM.  The huge setting you have could cause swapping, which is terrible for performance.  Ditto for `myisam_sort_buffer_size`, though it it probably not relevant to the Question.

You should consider moving from MyISAM to InnoDB, if for no other reason than avoiding corrupt indexes.  It will, however, increase the disk footprint (data + indexes) to upwards of 300GB.

InnoDB is much better at concurrent access to huge tables.

Comment: Thank you very much Rick! This is an import-once then read-only database. The buffers are only to quicken index building. I don't have really a swap. I provide pretty much RAM and a tmp path on a RAID0 for the indexing. For reading I rely on the Linux buffers. Unfortunately the huge Indexes won't fit in my RAM anyhow.

Comment: Please see above also my answer to why still keeping to the MyISAM engine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the advice of Rick James, to use InnoDB, was a good one, but it shouldn't take 7 days, of course.

To speeds up this process you can start with a table which doesn't have *any* indexes at all. Building the indexes is one of the reasons this process is so slow.

700,000,000 records is also a lot. You could split this into more manageable chucks. Say 700 files of 1 million records. See the [split command](https://linuxhandbook.com/split-command/). Writing a script that will load so many files will be essential.

After loading these files into a database table you can create the indexes one by one.

This is basically a "Divide and conquer" strategy. That being said, you are pushing the boundaries of what these databases normally have to cope with. My databases do normally grow to a few gigs, but rarely on a single table. I always try to keep my databases within reasonable size limits.

If my tables get really big, I use [partitioning](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partitioning-overview/) to make them more efficient. This is a "Divide and conquer" strategy build into MySQL. Note that you can partition your table before you've created all the indexes.

Finally, you could ask yourself if it is really necessary to store everything in a single table. Especially the `allele_string varchar(50000)` column could make your table very big. Why not put this in another table, or several other tables? If you create a script to load multiple smaller CSV files, you can also use that to disperse incoming data among several tables.

I'm sorry, but I have no real answer as to what's going wrong with your current setup. Everything tells me that it could work, but somehow it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations. This will bring me far afield from the SQL script found at ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-109/mysql/homo_sapiens_variation_109_38/homo_sapiens_variation_109_38.sql, which should be run as is. Their MyISAM version (MariaDB 10.0) is running well at "mysql --host=useastdb.ensembl.org --port=3306 --database=homo_sapiens_variation_109_38 --user=anonymous".  Based on this structure is running a whole framework of API's and programms, so I cannot move fields in another tables.

Comment: As stackoverflow is more for programming, I got a recommendation to cross post on dba.stackexchange.com, which - full ashamed but full despair - I did. If you see this there also, please don't scold me to bad

Comment: And for splitting and partitioning: I don't know how far I already got in a week, to interrupt it now

Comment: No, I agree, SO is not database-specific, so try another forum. There are some people here who know a lot more about databases than I do, and I'm surprised none of them reacted to your question. I think my tip of running the import without most indexes, and only add those later, is a good idea. This should not affect anything else and make the import easier.